# C++ builder's TSelection alternative in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, c++builder

I am rewriting some of my code from c++ builder to Qt, but can't find a replacement for TSelection int Qt, can anybody help?

in a nutshell, I want those dots around the control at runtime that qt designer shows for the control, so the user can simply resize the control at runtime by simply dragging

Comment: Not sure what you can do with a TSelection but it looks a bit like a QFrame

Comment: I want those dots around the control at runtime that qt designer shows for the control, so the user can simply resize the control at runtime by simply dragging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing is [`QRubberBand`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrubberband.html).

But it does not have the dots.